# My google scripts no longer runs

Tags: google-apps-script

I previously used this google script below to move information from one sheet to another sheet based on conditional values in one column (column#12). However, it just stopped responding/running recently and I cannot figure out why. I played with the triggers, I tried to use it in a new script and changing up some of the names and column#, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions on where I can look to find out what's going on?

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var r = ss.getActiveRange();
    if(s.getName() == "Phx-DFF" && r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == "no") 
    {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("NY-DFF");
        if(targetSheet.getLastRow() == targetSheet.getMaxRows()) 
        {
            targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 5); //inserts 20 rows after last used row
        }
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 14, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on the script purpose? Do you get any error message? You could try and add some debug statements as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#debugging)

Comment: The purpose of the script is that upon edit of column 12 of the script, and this edit is adding 'no', then that row will be moved into another sheet within the spreadsheet. Does this clarify the purpose?

Comment: And I don't get an error message when I debug, nothing happens when I click the debug button.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use logging or running the function in debug mode to see what exacly is happening when you run this function.

I want to suggest the follwing changes to the function as a lot of  information is provided by the eventinfo JSON:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = e.source;
var r = e.Range;

if(ss.getSheetName() == "Phx-DFF" && r.getColumn()  == 12 && e.value == "no") 
{
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("NY-DFF");
    if(targetSheet.getLastRow() == targetSheet.getMaxRows()) 
    {
        targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 5); //inserts 20 rows after last used row 
    }//I dont think this is necessary, GAS should takes care of this auto. Remove this part
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 14, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

Comment: when I click debug, it goes... 'Preparing for execution onedit'....and then 'debugging function onedit' and then nothing happens.

Comment: You need to specify a breakpoint, i.e a point where the script stops execution and you can check the values in the variables at that point in the execution (Do this by clicking to the left of the line number and a yelloow dot appears). Create a breakpoint on the first line of the if loop and run the debug mode, if the script does not stop then the loop is not being entered.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to figure it out!